# Visual Studio SSRS data source: Windows authentication - Use this user name and password

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, datasource

I am using Visual Studio 2015 with SSDT to develop reports with Report Services project.  I would like to create Shared Data Sources that use **"Windows Authentication with a specific user name and password" in this VS SSRS project**, (not "Windows Authentication with integrated security", which authenticates as my user account).

The data source is setup the desired way on the report portal already ("Windows with stored USER and PWD"). But I want it configured this way in the Visual Studio project so that all developers can open the project & develop with the data source connections, and also so that deployment of the project files to the server is more accurate.  I don't want to have to deploy it with "Windows integrated" then go the portal and manually configure the Shared Datasource-- that is a more error-prone deployment method.

It looks like the "Data Source Properties" screen is very similar for Report Builder and Visual Studio-- except Visual Studio is missing the missing the "Use as Windows credentials" checkbox option.

Does anyone have an answer for this Visual Studio option on the Data Source Property for "Windows Authentication with a specific user name and password"?

****Here are some screenshots:****

*VisualStudio-SharedDatasource-Properties.png* --> **option missing**

[image]

VisualStudio-Datasource-SQLServer-AuthenticationOptions --> **We are not using SQL Server User in our environment, it is Windows user.**

[image]

*ReportBuilder-rdl-Datasource-DatasourceProperties.png* --> **option is there**

[image]

*ReportPortal-SharedDatasource-Properties.png* --> **option is there**

[image]

Comment: I also was missing that functionality. The option is there, but it does not work. But: Shouldn't all developers have the permissions needed to access all the data? I think that using Windows Integrated Authentication should work perfecrly for all developers in Visual Studio SSDT. Since you already have deployed the Shared Datasources and have configured them to use a special Windows account, all should be perfect, as long as you make sure that the OverwriteDataSources property of the project is set to FALSE.

Comment: @WolfgangK.  Based on what I have seen, I think your answer is probably the best answer.  It looks like the feature simply doesn't exist in VS.  It seems that the maintenance of the data source must be done manually on the portal, which causes extra work when creating new data sources.  In my scenario I am trying to re-architect the report server in the VS Project and deploy to the Portal.  But it looks like that will not be a 100% automated push.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @SherlockSpreadsheets,

I can bring you a workaround: Choice "Windows Authentication" and then add the required credentials at Credential Manager with the below steps:

1. Open Control Panel.
2. Open User Accounts.
3. Click Manage My Network Passwords on the Related Tasks panel (on the
   left side of the window). You'll get a dialog box listing all of
   your stored usernames and passwords. Add another username and
   password, or remove the existing ones or change their properties.

Comment: Hi @Negarrak,  I have tried to follow your directions; I do not see "Manage My Network Passwords".  I am using Windows 7, and I tried these two Control Panels-- "**Control Panel\User Accounts**" and "**Control Panel\User Accounts\User Accounts**".

Comment: For anyone else reading this... The Control Panel Credentials Manager "stored credentials" totally backfired for me after resetting my Windows Password.  I could not access the Report Portal via Chrome or IE.  Was very frustrating, but deleting the credentials fixed that problem.